# How to change other kv string's property in kivymd?

Tags: list, kivy, python-3.8, kivymd

I was using kivymd MDList, but I have a problem.

My Code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

example_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

KV = """
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        id: List
"""

ListItem = """
OneLineAvatarListItem:
    id: item
    text: ""
    ImageLeftWidget:
        source: "icon.png"
"""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        for letter in example_list:
            self.root.ids.item.text = letter
            self.root.ids.List.add_widget(Builder.load_string(ListItem))

MainApp().run()
```

I want to display List like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WddvU.jpg), But my code occurs this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "kivy\properties.pyx", line 861, in kivy.properties.ObservableDict.__getattr__
 KeyError: 'item'
```

I think `ListItem` is not root, but I don't know how to solve this.

How can I change ListItem's text property?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be one, I don't use KivyMD a lot, but seeing the widget, there isn't a text property over there

Comment: Ok. My mistake. There is text property in ListItem. I'll edit.

Comment: I think that you need to create a normal BoxLayout and add a ListItem for every letter

Comment: Oh. I definitely don't want to do that... Is there any way to do this with loop?

Comment: Oh nono, you will use a loop, just give me some time, I will try to answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of loading the widget from a kv string, making it in python would be easier for this case, just create the MDList normally and in every iteration of the loop, create a new OneLineAvatarListItem Widget, set its properties, add the image, then add the whole widget to the MDList.

**Code**

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarListItem, ImageLeftWidget
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder

example_list = ['a', 'b', 'c']

KV = """
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        id: List
"""

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
        global example_list
        for letter in example_list:
            one_line = OneLineAvatarListItem(text = letter)
            image = ImageLeftWidget(source = "icon.png")
            one_line.add_widget(image)
            self.root.ids.List.add_widget(one_line)

MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Thank you! But my last question: in PyCharm, it works well but it shows warning  `Unexpected argument` on `source = "icon.png"`. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: @JayLee probably because the __init__ does not have a source argument, try doing this `image = ImageLeftWidget()` then on next line `image.source = "icon.png"`

Comment: @JayLee happy to help :)